# Custom created Polygons don't display on Folium map

Tags: coordinate-system, polygon, folium

I've got a Geopandas Dataframe (polygon_df) that looks like the one below, these Polygons were created by a Yolo segmentation algorithm and transformed twice from their original format *(this information might not be relevant, but I want to mention it in case this might be the source of the problem, although I really don't think so).*

Context: These Polygons represent segmentations of Solar Panels in Nijmegen Zuid, Netherlands, Europe. It's using the CRS: EPSG 3857.

```
    geometry
0   POLYGON ((648745.973 6764605.655, 648745.491 6...
1   POLYGON ((648709.785 6764626.587, 648709.304 6...
2   POLYGON ((648836.827 6764923.395, 648836.346 6...
3   POLYGON ((648283.746 6764392.271, 648283.426 6...
4   POLYGON ((648306.009 6764390.681, 648305.688 6...
5   POLYGON ((647965.957 6764363.920, 647962.427 6...
6   POLYGON ((648294.882 6764392.204, 648294.562 6...
7   POLYGON ((648211.211 6764461.638, 648210.409 6...
8   POLYGON ((648134.469 6764529.251, 648134.149 6...
9   POLYGON ((648158.487 6764524.252, 648158.005 6...
10  POLYGON ((648222.337 6764459.953, 648221.535 6...
11  POLYGON ((648146.079 6764527.563, 648145.277 6...
12  POLYGON ((647950.464 6764364.012, 647949.981 6...
```

To give you a specific example, here's the first Polygon at index 0:

```
POLYGON ((648745.973276913 6764605.655278085, 648745.4910600245 6764605.9818336405, 648744.6841049957 6764605.986736484, 648744.6860610727 6764606.310350303, 648744.3662131444 6764606.797732187, 648744.3681692092 6764607.121346041, 648743.8869301918 6764607.609708505, 648743.8888862377 6764607.9333224, 648743.5690381979 6764608.420704346, 648743.084865034 6764608.423645939, 648741.1599079994 6764610.377095788, 648740.6757347177 6764610.380037242, 648739.0716030499 6764612.007912029, 648738.748820797 6764612.00987292, 648736.021795374 6764614.777259965, 648735.5376218278 6764614.78020111, 648733.9334882596 6764616.408075755, 648733.6107058297 6764616.410036441, 648732.3273984597 6764617.7123361165, 648732.0046159776 6764617.714296732, 648730.8817216454 6764618.8538089115, 648730.3975478533 6764618.856749747, 648730.4004811208 6764619.342171271, 648729.5984134512 6764620.156108539, 648729.275630871 6764620.158069051, 648728.47258529 6764620.810199086, 648728.4755184433 6764621.29562072, 648727.9932999208 6764621.622175859, 648727.6705172819 6764621.62413631, 648726.0663807831 6764623.252010765, 648725.5822067265 6764623.254951313, 648725.5851397079 6764623.740373105, 648725.2643122922 6764624.065947993, 648725.2789771105 6764626.493057443, 648725.6046929284 6764626.976519072, 648725.6066482513 6764627.300133737, 648728.5283152696 6764630.033215133, 648728.5312484306 6764630.518637316, 648728.8559868766 6764630.840291634, 648729.3401613841 6764630.837350879, 648730.1520076595 6764631.641486634, 648730.1549409181 6764632.12690891, 648730.4796794929 6764632.448563234, 648730.9638540957 6764632.445622378, 648731.2846816127 6764632.120046926, 648732.0916392503 6764632.115145405, 648733.2135574297 6764630.813823806, 648733.6977319336 6764630.810882789, 648735.6226956045 6764628.85742982, 648736.1068699905 6764628.854488657, 648736.1039363776 6764628.369066573, 648736.4247635271 6764628.04349108, 648736.9089378641 6764628.040549874, 648738.8339001049 6764626.087096801, 648739.1566829178 6764626.0851359, 648742.3649511295 6764622.829380672, 648742.8491251529 6764622.826439107, 648744.4532581959 6764621.198561417, 648744.7760408126 6764621.196600294, 648746.3801731468 6764619.568722541, 648746.7029556981 6764619.566761345, 648747.1851733436 6764619.240205172, 648747.1822390726 6764618.754783669, 648747.9843048376 6764617.940844798, 648748.3070873239 6764617.938883532, 648749.9112183059 6764616.3110057255, 648750.3953919366 6764616.308063716, 648751.9995221776 6764614.680185829, 648752.3223045329 6764614.678224411, 648753.1243693795 6764613.8642854355, 648753.1224129637 6764613.540671312, 648752.7966960497 6764613.0572115965, 648752.7947396472 6764612.733597499, 648750.6849169295 6764610.804662315, 648750.6819824531 6764610.319241313, 648749.0582902764 6764608.710978144, 648749.0563340242 6764608.387364225, 648748.7306175597 6764607.903904647, 648748.7286613208 6764607.580290753, 648748.2415538809 6764607.097811851, 648748.2366633335 6764606.288777231, 648747.9119251049 6764605.967124654, 648747.4277520896 6764605.970066503, 648747.1030139058 6764605.64841392, 648745.973276913 6764605.655278085))
```

I'm trying to plot these Polygons on an interactive **Folium map**.

This is my code:

```
import folium
from folium import GeoJson
center_latitude = polygon_df['geometry'].centroid.y.mean()
center_longitude = polygon_df['geometry'].centroid.x.mean()
mymap = folium.Map(location=[center_latitude, center_longitude], zoom_start=15)
geojson = GeoJson(polygon_df,
                  style_function=lambda feature: {
                      'fillColor': 'green',  # Change the fill color as needed
                      'color': 'black',       # Change the border color as needed
                      'weight': 10,
                      'fillOpacity': 0.6,
                  })
geojson.add_to(mymap)
print(mymap)
```

The problem here is twofold,

1. When the map gets displayed it should center itself on the centroid with zoom level 15 however, it centers itself at an area above the actual map of the world in a white area. When I input these centroid coordinates with proper CRS in EPSG.io website (https://epsg.io/map#srs=3857&x=648306.9914587656&y=6764514.624681651&z=13&layer=streets) it does display the correct area somewhere in Nijmegen Zuid, Netherlands which is strange.
2. When I zoom into the correct area in Nijmegen Zuid, none of the Polygons show.

What am I doing wrong here?

Comment: You are feeding projected coordinates to GeoJson, but it expects EPSG:4326.